# No Parameterless Constructor defined for - ViewModel with UOW

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, viewmodel

I have a view model class which uses `UnitOfWork` to some database operations like fetching of items to create select lists and `IPrincipal` for some auditing (like modified by etc.). It cannot work without this UOW. I have configured my web site to use `Ninject` to inject UOW into `Controller`s. From controller I pass this UOW when creating view model. But when performing `POST` operation I am getting

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

I have few `SelectList` type of properties which I have excluded with `Bind` attribute.

How can I overcome this problem? Can I configure `Ninject` to create the objects of this type and make `ModelBinder` use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps inheriting from DefaultModelBinder and resolving the model classes via Ninject?

Update:

**NinjectModelBinder.cs**

```
public class NinjectModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private readonly StandardKernel _kernel;

    public NinjectModelBinder(StandardKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                              ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var model = _kernel.TryGet(modelType);
        if (model != null) return model;
        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new NinjectModelBinder(kernel);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing the light but I will need a little bit of more elaboration.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot I've updated my answer with an actual implementation.

Comment: that's great. Fitted in. Can we somehow get the `IPrincipal` also? I am pushing it from `Controller.User`.

Comment: How about using the static `HttpContext.Current.User`?

Comment: well well... coming from full-time `WebForms` development need to explore MVC bit more deeply. thanks a lot you made my day :)

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot I Hope you like MVC, I sure do.